# Email and password confirmation with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I'm making a jQuery form validation:

Password and username validation is working as expected while the email and password confirmation aren't, though I use the same technique for both.

Here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vPSm6/)

The problem is that I'm not getting any console errors, they just don't work.

## HTML

```
    <title> Sign Up </title>
<body>
<div class=left></div>
<form method="post" action="" >
<table align=" top-center" >
<tr>
    <td><input type='text' placeholder='User name' name='uname' id=u required= 'required' ></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <div id=uname_info class=info>
<h4>Username must meet the following requirements:</h4>
<ul>
<li id=uletter class=valid> Start with a <strong>letter</strong>
<li id=ulength class=invalid> Be at least <strong> 4 characters</strong>
</ul>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type='Email' placeholder="Email0" name='em' ></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >
<div class=info>
<div id='remail'class=invalid> 
<h4 > The email you typed is incorrect<h4>
</div>
</div>
</tr>
<tr>
    
    <td><input type='password' placeholder='password' name=pa1 id=p1></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="pswd_info" class=info>
<h4>Password must meet the following requirements:</h4>

        <ul>
            <li id="letter" class="invalid">At least <strong>one letter</strong>

            </li>
            <li id="capital" class="invalid">At least <strong>one capital letter</strong>

            </li>
            <li id="number" class="invalid">At least <strong>one number</strong>

            </li>
            <li id="length" class="invalid">Be at least <strong>8 characters</strong>

            </li>
        </ul>
</div></tr>
<tr>
    
    <td><input type='password' placeholder='Repeat password' name=pa2></input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="pswd2_info" class="info">
<h4><strong class=invalid> Passwords Do not match</strong></h4>
</div>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td></td>
    
    <td><center> <input type='submit' name=submit value='Submit'></center></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>


</body>
```

## jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {



 $('#u').keyup(function () {
    // set password variable
    var uname = $(this).val();
    var uRegEx = /^[a-zA-Z]/;
    var first = uname.charAt(0);
    if (uname.length < 4) {
        $('#ulength').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    } else {
        $('#ulength').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    }
    //validate letter
    if (first != uRegEx.exec(first)) {
        $('#uletter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    } else {
        $('#uletter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    }

    if ($('#uname_info li.invalid').length == 0) {
        $('#uname_info').fadeOut('slow');
    } else {
        $('#uname_info').fadeIn('slow');
        
    }
});
$('#u').focus(function () {
    // focus code here
});
$('#u').blur(function () {
    // blur code here
});

$('#u').keyup(function () {

    // keyup code here
}).focus(function () {
    $('#fname_info').show();
}).blur(function () {
    $('#fname_info').hide();
});
$('#em').blur(function () {
function isValidEmail(emailText) {
var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
return pattern.test(emailText);
};
if( !isValidEmail(myEmail) )
{$('#remail').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
}
else
{$('#remail').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');}
}); 
$('#em').focus(function () {
    // focus code here
});
$('#em').blur(function () {
    // blur code here
});

$('#em').keyup(function () {

    // keyup code here
}).focus(function () {
    $('#remail').show();
}).blur(function () {
    $('#remail').hide();
}); 
$('#p1').keyup(function () {
    // set password variable
    var pswd = $(this).val();
    if (pswd.length < 8) {
        $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    } else {
        $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    }
    //validate letter
    if (pswd.match(/[A-z]/)) {
        $('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    } else {
        $('#letter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    }
    //validate capital letter
    if (pswd.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
        $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    } else {
        $('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    }

    //validate number
    if (pswd.match(/\d/)) {
        $('#number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    } else {
        $('#number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    }

    if ($('#pswd_info li.invalid').length == 0) {
        $('#pswd_info').fadeOut('fast');
    } else {
        $('#pswd_info').fadeIn('fast');

    }
});

$('#p1').focus(function () {
    // focus code here
});
$('#p1').blur(function () {
    // blur code here
});

$('#p1').keyup(function () {

    // keyup code here
}).focus(function () {
    $('#pswd_info').show();
}).blur(function () {
    $('#pswd_info').hide();
}); 


$('#pa2').blur(function () {

var pswd2 = $('#pa2').val();
if(pswd != pswd2)
{
$('#pswd2_info').fadeIn();
}
else
{$('#pswd2_info').fadeOut();
}
});

});
```

I see no need for giving the css (though you can view it in the fiddle).
I tried to debug the code so I commented the part of username and password validation and I'm sure there is nothing wrong with it. So I'm sure the error is in this part:

```
$('#pa2').blur(function () {
    
    var pswd2 = $('#pa2').val();
    if(pswd != pswd2)
    {
    $('#pswd2_info').fadeIn();
    }
    else
    {$('#pswd2_info').fadeOut();
    }
    });
```

and/or this part :

```
$('#em').blur(function () {
    function isValidEmail(emailText) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
    return pattern.test(emailText);
    };
    if( !isValidEmail(myEmail) )
    {$('#remail').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    }
    else
    {$('#remail').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');}
    }); 
    $('#em').focus(function () {
        // focus code here
    });
    $('#em').blur(function () {
        // blur code here
    });

    $('#em').keyup(function () {

        // keyup code here
    }).focus(function () {
        $('#remail').show();
    }).blur(function () {
        $('#remail').hide();
    });
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be a few things.

### Email

1) You're selecting the email input with an id selector, so add the proper id.

```
    <input id='em' type='email' placeholder="Email" name='em'>
```

This will allow your blur to actually get triggered.

Now, you *will* get an error in the console. myEmail is not defined, as it isn't. Go ahead and assign it to the value of the email input

```
    $('#em').blur(function () {
    myEmail = $('this').val();
```

2) Rather than applying invalid and valid to a div, you'll probably want to add them to a list item as you did in the username.

```
    <div id=email_info class=info>
       <h4> The email you typed is incorrect: </h4>
       <ul>
         <li id=eformat class=invalid> 
           A valid email format looks like: username@example.com
         </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
```

And then apply the fading in and out as you did before

```
      if (isValidEmail(myEmail)){ 
        $('#email_info').fadeOut('slow');
      } else {
        $('#email_info').fadeIn('slow');
      }
```

This will fix email. See your updated Gist [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vPSm6/3/)

### Password Confirmation

As for password confirmation, you need to add the same id you're selecting again.

```
  <td><input id='pa2' type='password' placeholder='Repeat password' name=pa2></input>
```

Since you are selecting it with pa2 here

```
  $('#pa2').blur(function () {
```

Also, you'll need to define pswd along with the already defined pswd2.

```
  var pswd = $('#pa1').val();
  var pswd2 = $('#pa2').val();
```

This should fix both problems. See updated gist [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vPSm6/4/)

Comment: Thanks, I guess my problem is that I'm mixing between php and javascript.

Comment: Very welcome, I'm glad I could help. I'd recommend throwing your html into a validator and aligner as well.  It really pays off to have the tags aligned properly when eyeballing the DOM. Some free ones - [HTML Validator](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html) and [HTML Code Aligner](http://www.dirtymarkup.com/). Also, [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) is a great one for JavaScript. Depending on the text editor or IDE you use you may have one built in or available as a plugin as well. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Isn' t there a typo here?

```
    if( !isValidEmail(myEmail) ){
       $('#remail').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    }
    else{
       $('#remail').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    }
```

The both lines are equal!

Comment: Thanks I fixed it in my code but still the div doesn't appear in the first place.